# how to use eval function on this column I have json response on this column

Tags: python, json, pandas, database, eval

[Dataframe looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1pTY.png)

I want to evaluate the strings using Eval function,

using the code: df['account_Segments'] = df['account_Segments'].apply(lambda x:eval(str(x)))

so that I can flatten this column in next step using flatten nested json function.

[This is the error while using eval function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRKuA.png)

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your dataframe ?

Comment: col1 = LAI-100518437 
col2 = "[{""accountType"": ""Consumer Loan"", ""currentBalance"": ""9,250"", ""paymentHistory1"": ""000 000 000 000 000 000 ""},{""accountType"": ""Credit Card"", ""currentBalance"": ""26,841"", ""paymentHistory1"": ""000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 XXX 000 000 ""}]"

Comment: @JulienSorin col2 is supposed to be in json format but when i read csv it had two columns, so i used sep = ";" instead of comma, which ended creating this format with multiple quotes

Comment: I don't see any `account_Segments` key in your sample. Do you have one ?

Comment: can you show an example of the expected Ouput in your question please ?

Comment: @JulienSorin

data = {'APPLICATION ID' : ['LAI-100518437'], 'account_Segments' :  ['"[{""accountType"": ""Consumer Loan"", ""currentBalance"": ""9,250"", ""paymentHistory1"": ""000 000 000 000 000 000 ""},{""accountType"": ""Credit Card"", ""currentBalance"": ""26,841"", ""paymentHistory1"": ""000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 XXX 000 000 ""}]"']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
note that i have showed only 1 row sample but have used [' '] for values of dictionary